# How to print the triangle pattern of numbers 1 to 15 in python?

Tags: python

[This image is my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JDMs.jpg) While printing the triangle pattern from 1 to 15 numbers in 5 number of rows. I have gone through some error.

Comment: Post your code, along with a specific question about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Please make sure your title matches the text.

Comment: As this is my first time in asking question in stack overflow I had gone through some issues. could you please reopen my question sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print 1 to 21 then

```
Next = 1
for s in range(0, 6):  
    for t in range(0, s + 1):  
        print(Next, end=' ')  
        Next= Next + 1  
    print()
```

Output :

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21
```

If you want to print 1 to 15 then

```
Next = 1
for s in range(0, 5):  
    for t in range(0, s + 1):  
        print(Next, end=' ')  
        Next= Next + 1  
    print()
```

Output :

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: Don't write code for people.  This question was closed for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code works for you. Solution with O[N] complexity.

```
col = 0
curr = 1
N = 15
for i in range(1,N+1):
  if curr <col:    
    curr+=1
  else:
    print()
    col+=1
    curr=1
  print(i,end=' ')
```

Comment: Don't write code for people.  This question was closed for a reason.